# MySQL Не работает LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

Делаю LEFT JOIN таблицы саму на себя

```
SELECT t1.id ,t1.parent_id, t2.id, t2.parent_id 
FROM answers AS t1 
LEFT JOIN answers AS t2";
```

Не работает, но если сделать тоже самое, но убрать слово LEFT

```
SELECT t1.id ,t1.parent_id, t2.id, t2.parent_id 
FROM answers AS t1 
JOIN answers AS t2";
```

Тогда все работает, но мне нужен LEFT JOIN

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` требует ***обязательного*** наличия условия связывания (секция `ON`). В то время как для `INNER JOIN` наличие этой секции не обязательно. Что собственно и наблюдается.

Comment: А чего именно вы хотите получить на выходе. ваш первый запрос перемножает каждую запись таблицы на каждую, так как нет условия  соединения. такое объединение используется крайне редко. И ситуации когда при таком объединении понадобился left мне в голову не приходит, потому что без условия объединения для любой записи таблицы и так уже подходят _все_ записи, а следовательно нет таких записей для которых бы пары не нашлось. А LEFT нужен как раз что бы показать записи для которых нет пары, но у вас то их заведомо быть не может

Comment: Я не вижу причин, по которым второй запрос может работать, в то время как первый "не работает". Либо Вы чего-то не договариваете, либо одно из двух. Да и что вообще за модная фраза "не работает"? Ошибку хоть выведите людям, в самом деле.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо указать связь `ON`. Ее можно не указывать только для `CROSS JOIN`, который вероятно и происходит в MySQL при отсутствии вида соединения.

```
SELECT t1.id ,t1.parent_id, t2.id, t2.parent_id 
FROM answers AS t1 
LEFT JOIN answers AS t2 on t1.id = t2.parent_id;
```

Comment: Добавьте объяснение в свой ответ, чтобы другие легче восприняли его